# Defining start date of flag event in a data.table

Tags: r, date, data.table, flags

I have a `data.table` like the following with many IDs:

```
      ID Date        Flag
      1  2016.01.01  0
      1  2016.02.01  0
      1  2016.03.01  0
      1  2016.04.01  1
      1  2016.05.01  1
      1  2016.06.01  1
      1  2016.07.01  0
      1  2016.08.01  0
      1  2016.09.01  1
      1  2016.10.01  1
      1  2016.11.01  1
      1  2016.12.01  0
      1  2017.01.01  0
      1  2017.02.01  0
```

I would like to define a date variable based on the flag with the following logic (the date should show the start date of the next or currently effective flag event:

```
      ID Date        Flag Date_of_flag_event
      1  2016.01.01  0    2016.04.01
      1  2016.02.01  0    2016.04.01
      1  2016.03.01  0    2016.04.01
      1  2016.04.01  1    2016.04.01
      1  2016.05.01  1    2016.04.01
      1  2016.06.01  1    2016.04.01
      1  2016.07.01  0    2016.09.01
      1  2016.08.01  0    2016.09.01
      1  2016.09.01  1    2016.09.01
      1  2016.10.01  1    2016.09.01
      1  2016.11.01  1    2016.09.01
      1  2016.12.01  0    NA
      1  2017.01.01  0    NA
      1  2017.02.01  0    NA
```

Please help me with this variable

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option.  Create a grouping variable with `diff` and `cumsum` based on the 'Flag' variable, then assign (`:=`) the 'Date' that corresponds to the first instance where 'Flag' is 1 as 'Date_of_flag_event'

```
dt1[,  Date_of_flag_event := Date[which(Flag == 1)[1]], cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Flag) < 0))]
dt1
#     ID       Date Flag Date_of_flag_event
# 1:  1 2016.01.01    0         2016.04.01
# 2:  1 2016.02.01    0         2016.04.01
# 3:  1 2016.03.01    0         2016.04.01
# 4:  1 2016.04.01    1         2016.04.01
# 5:  1 2016.05.01    1         2016.04.01
# 6:  1 2016.06.01    1         2016.04.01
# 7:  1 2016.07.01    0         2016.09.01
# 8:  1 2016.08.01    0         2016.09.01
# 9:  1 2016.09.01    1         2016.09.01
#10:  1 2016.10.01    1         2016.09.01
#11:  1 2016.11.01    1         2016.09.01
#12:  1 2016.12.01    0                 NA
#13:  1 2017.01.01    0                 NA
#14:  1 2017.02.01    0                 NA
```

Comment: Hi, akrun, could you help me complement this code, so the Date_of_flag_event is grouped by "ID" as well?

Comment: @Martonka, You can use `by = .(ID, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Flag) < 0)))]`